# Fancybox: Get id of clicked anchor/element

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to get the id of the clicked/shown element in fancybox. I have tried both "this.id" and "this.attr("id")" - but none of them works.

```
$("a.lightbox_image").fancybox({
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'speedIn': 600,
            'speedOut': 200,
            'content': 'Id of element clicked'+this.attr("id")
 });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("a.lightbox_image").each(function() {
  $(this).fancybox({
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'speedIn': 600,
        'speedOut': 200,
        'content': 'Id of element clicked' + this.id
  });
});
```

`this` refers  probably to `window` where you're binding currently (or `document` if in the `ready` event, can't be sure without seeing more code). For `this` to be the `<a>` like you want, you should use a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop and assign it there...inside the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) closure, `this` refers to the anchor.

Comment: Afraid not - already tried that, and it just returns "undefined"

Comment: SORRY - i did not notice you other changes besides the "+ this.id" - just tried it, and now it works like a charm. Thx :)

Comment: @kastru: Great :)  Be sure to accept answers is the solve your problem! helps everyone, including you getting answers faster in the future :)

Comment: I apprantly have to wait 10 minutes from submission until i can accept an answer :)

Comment: This destroys my gallery effect with rel="", how come?

Answer (score 9):

I had problems using Nick Craver's solution together with "onClosed" function and after some tests I found working solution:

```
$("a.lightbox_image").each(function() {
  var tthis = this;
  $(this).fancybox({
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'speedIn': 600,
        'speedOut': 200,
        onClosed : function() {
           alert(this.id);
     }
  });
});
```

This, in my case, was used to reload row with data after closing fancybox window where that data was edited.

Comment: This is the solution when do you use events. Thanks

Comment: better to use `button` or `clickedButton` instead of `tthis`

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me :)

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <a class="fancybox" title="MyTitle" rel="group" href="#" id="fiid_4">
        <img src="/dir/image4.png" alt="x" style="width:200px;height:160px;"  />
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" title="MyTitle" rel="group" href="#" id="fiid_5">
        <img src="/dir/image5.png" alt="x" style="width:200px;height:160px;"  />
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" title="MyTitle" rel="group" href="#" id="fiid_6">
        <img src="/dir/image6.png" alt="x" style="width:200px;height:160px;"  />
    </a>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
            loop : false,
            afterLoad: function(current, previous) {
                console.log(this.element[0].id)
                console.info( 'Current: ' + current.href );        
                console.info( 'Previous: ' + (previous ? previous.href : '-') );

                if (previous) {
                    console.info( 'Navigating: ' + (current.index > previous.index ? 'right' : 'left') );


                    //When navigating, we want to add the next set of images! :)
                    new_images = getNextFancyImages(current.index > previous.index ? 'right' : 'left')
                }
            }
        });
});
```

In firebug, you can see the logging :)

Comment: Using $( this.element[0] ) inside afterLoad gives the element, which you can use however like $( this.element[0] ).attr( 'id' )

Answer (score 2):

The answers which suggest using an each loop are correct, but if you're using any of the callbacks (beforeShow, beforeLoad, onUpdate etc) there's one important detail to understand.

In the context of your each loop, **this** refers to the element which will get clicked. 
But as soon as you're inside the fancybox callback, **this** refers to the fancybox object. 
The trick is to store the elements **this** into another variable, e.g **that**. 
Then refer to **that** in your callback.

```
$('.fancybox').each(function() {
   var that = this;
   $(this).fancybox({
      beforeLoad: function() {
          var id = $(that).attr('id');
          console.log("id of element clicked is: "+id)
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `each(function()` solution breaks the gallery (in other words, no more Next and Prev button).

A solution that seems to work and saves the gallery is to assign a function to the click event on the element before fancyBox is called and save the id to a unique div.

For instance:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").click(function() { $("#<unique_div>").data("clickedid", this.id); }).fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            this.title += '<br />';
            this.title += 'Clicked id: ' + $("#<unique_div>").data("clickedid");
        },
        prevEffect: 'none',
        nextEffect: 'none',
        loop: false,
        fitToView: false,
        helpers: { title: { type: 'inside' }  }
    });
});
```