# jQuery Fancybox get id value of a

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

what I'm trying to do is get the ID value of the referring a. The code for my a looks like:

```
<a class="photoBig" id="<?php echo $photo['id'] ?>" href="<?php echo $f->buildPhotoURL($photo, 'large') ?>" title="<?php echo $photo['title'] ?>">
```

I'm using phpFlickr to assign the ID's plus some various other things, which works fine.

So the code to open a Fancybox I use is:

```
$("a.photoBig").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
            'titleShow'     : true,
            'overlayOpacity' : 0.9,
            'overlayColor' : '#000',
            'autoScale' : false,
            'scrolling' : true,
            'titlePosition' : 'inside',
            'showNavArrows' : true,
            'cyclic' : true,
            'showCloseButton' : false,
            'titleFormat' : formatTitle
        });
```

then the function fomatTitle, which is:

```
function formatTitle(title, id, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
    return '<div id="photoBig-title"><span><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.fancybox.close();"><img src="images/site/closelabel.gif"></a></span>' + (title && title.length ? '<strong>' + title + '</strong>' : '' ) + $(this).id + '<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/rustybones/' + this.id + '" title="view original on flickr">view full size</a></div>';
}
```

Everything works in this function except for this.id. Obviously I'm doing this wrong, so any help would be tops! Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming there is more than one a tag on the page with the matching class?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961496/fancybox-get-id-of-clicked-anchor-element.

See if that helps.

Comment: Yup there are a series of images with the same class. I tried the solution you linked to, but when the Fancybox pops up it just has "Id of element clicked 4093839" so that string of numbers is the ID I'm after but I want to put that ID into my formatTitle function, specifically into my a href.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Change</strike>

`$(this).id`
to
`this.id`
or
`$(this).attr('id')`

and see if that works.

**EDIT:** Okay, I've tested this and it works:

Use `currentArray[currentIndex].id` to get the id.

Alternatively, if all you wanted was the id so you could use it to point to your image, you could  just use $(this).attr('href') in it.

Comment: No go, it just returns "undefined".

Comment: I see that in your function, you are using both $(this).id and this.id. Did you try changing both of them to $(this).attr('id')? What do you mean returns undefined, is that what is said in the box or when you click the link?